# Using React-Spring useSprings only on active button in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I am trying to animate a position change of the active box. When the user clicks on the box, I would like the box to animate a margin-top change and the rest of the boxes to stay at 0px. When the user changes the active box, the previously active box will return to 0px and the new active box will acquire a margin-top of 50px.

I think I am nearly there but I haven't quite managed to get it to work yet. I would be really grateful if someone could help enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong.

```
import { useSpring, useSprings, animated } from "react-spring";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Nav = () => {

  // Set Active Box
 const [activeBox, setActiveBox] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    setActiveBox(index);
  };

// Boxes
  const boxes = [box1, box2, box3, box4];


// useSprings 
  const springs = useSprings(
    boxes.length,
    boxes.map((box, index) => ({
      marginTop: activeBox === index ? 50 : 0,
    }))
  );

  return (
    <NavContainer>
      {springs.map((prop, index) => (
        <StyledBox
          style={prop}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
          currentActiveBox={activeBox === index}
        >
          <img src={boxes[index]} alt="" />
        </StyledBox>
      ))}
    </NavContainer>
  );
};

export default Nav;

const NavContainer = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
`;

const StyledBox = styled.div`
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

`;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that animated was not added to the styled component!

```
const StyledBox = styled(animated.div)`
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```